# SQL Group By and AGGREGATE help needed

Tags: mysql

I have two tables...

- Orders(orderNumber,orderDate,shippedDate,requiredDate,status,customerNumber) and
- OrderDetails(orderNumber,productCode,quantityOrdered,priceEach,orderLineNumber)

I'm trying to return a query like this...

```
+----------------------------------+--------------------+
| DATEDIFF(shippedDate, orderDate) | COUNT(shippedDate) |
+----------------------------------+--------------------+
|                                1 |                 50 |
|                                2 |                 49 |
|                                3 |                 52 |
|                                4 |                 52 |
|                                5 |                 59 |
|                                6 |                 45 |
|                                7 |                  2 |
|                                8 |                  2 |
|                               65 |                  1 |
+----------------------------------+--------------------+
```

but I'm just not getting it.  I know I have to do a group by and use DateDiff() and Count()...

I've tried this but its not right
mysql:

```
select DATEDIFF(shippedDate,orderDate), COUNT(shippedDate) from Orders Group by shippedDate;
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Removed the SQL Server tag because question explicitly say "mysql".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `group by` the `datediff()`:

```
select DATEDIFF(shippedDate, orderDate), COUNT(shippedDate)
from Orders
Group by DATEDIFF(shippedDate, orderDate);
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I wanted to remove the NULL value?

Comment: @dognose . . . (1) The SQL tag is often used in conjunction with other databases.  Its purpose seems to be to expand the audience.  (2) This wouldn't work in SQL Server because `datediff()` takes three arguments in SQL Server.  (3) I'm not sure what you are saying.  With the third argument to `datediff()`, this would work in SQL Server.

Comment: @user3740517 . . . You would add something like `where shippedDate is not null and orderDate is not null` or perhaps replace the `NULL` value with `now()` using `coalesce()`.

Comment: Works great with the WHERE...IS NOT NULL.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add datediff(shippedDate,orderDate) in group by statement instead of shippedDate